# Replace a thumbnail with another in google chrome new tab page?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, thumbnails

I have 8 thumbnails in my google chrome new tab page... Two have been blocked in my company...
How to replace that two thumbnails with new ones....

Comment: Simple start using a home page extension like Speed Dial ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove thumbnails displayed for specific sites, hover over a thumbnail with your mouse. When the blue frame appears around the thumbnail, click the x that appears in the top right corner of the frame. Thumbnails that you remove won't show up on the New Tab page again, unless you click  at the top right corner of the page and select Restore all removed thumbnails. . then drop it and you can [manually add a thumbnail](https://superuser.com/questions/57745/can-i-manually-add-a-thumbnail-web-page-to-the-chrome-homepage) webpage to chrome home page.

Also that thumbnails are for Most visited sites and Recently closed windows and tabs.

Comment: The newer version of Chrome appear to have removed the thing in the top right hand corner that allows you to restore thumbnails. You can get the option by removing another thumbnail and then selecting the restore all thumbnails option that appears in the middle of the screen.

Comment: As of today's latest version, when you remove a thumbnail the options to Undo or Restore All are shown underneath the thumbnail grid for about 10 seconds or so (I didn't time how long.)

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked how to add their own thumbnails in Google Chrome. Google Chrome does not have this option but you can do it by yourself:

1. First create a bookmark of the page.
2. Now right-click on the bookmark and select *Edit*.
3. Copy the address of this bookmark by marking it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
4. Open a new Tab with your bookmarks and select any bookmark there that you don't need any more.
5. Right-click and select *Inspect Element*. A VB screen will open.
6. Search for a string containing the hyperlink (e.g. `<a href="http://www.…">Product Reviews</a>`
7. Look carefully and first change the name of the bookmark—in this case it is *Product Reviews* (Only change the text between the quotes.)
8. Now search for the next string that starts with `http://www.…` and just select that text up to the next `"` and replace it by pasting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) it with your bookmark's reference that you copied earlier.
9. Go out there and you will first see that your thumbnail will look funny.
10. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh and your thumbnail is fixed!

Comment: Down-vote:that will only change that instance of the page, reboot, close chrome or even navigate to a new page that change is lost.

Answer (score -1):

If you have removed a thumbnail you added it to a blacklist

That same site will never be allowed back in as a thumbnail ever again

You have to manually edit the Json file called Preferences in the user/appdata for chrome.

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong as indicated in the accepted answer "click at the top right corner of the page and select Restore all removed thumbnails"