# How do I get the deleted choices back in Google Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

On the initial screen of Google Chrome there are some choices. I deleted one a while ago and now I want to put it back. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean the "most visited" pages under the new tab page?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the "most visited" "pages" (under the new tab page) where multiple websites that you visit a lot are "posted", you can restore the ones you have deleted by just clicking on that little arrow/button in the upper right corner and select "restore all removed thumbnails."

Comment: note that this thread here: http://superuser.com/questions/57745/can-i-manually-add-a-thumbnail-web-page-to-the-chrome-homepage is also very helpful.